# Trying to check 4 different factors for a valid combination

Tags: microsoft-excel

All right, this is going to be tricky to explain, but I'll try.

Very simple sample sheet at: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dubljQcN25o7FAPS6F8u1VOeyHqg8D3tEZS1XldG5vE/edit#gid=0

I have a long list of data with basically 4 important columns: name of a person, a unique ID number, a 'type' column and a 'quantity' column. When the same unique ID# has more than one 'type', we add each entry separately one below the other, so you can have 1 row at minimum and 4 at maximum.

My ultimate goal is to sift through all the entries and determine which people are to be approved and which to be refused. This is determined by whether or not certain numerical parameters are fulfilled. As an example: if a person has 88 Apples he *must* have 22 Oranges as well. Another example would be a person cannot have more than 20 Bananas, above all. There are quite a few of these rules, but you get the idea. If any of these criteria are not fulfilled, I need to know.

My best idea so far would be to create an auxiliary sheet with all the possible combinations of the 4 values (I'm not sure if this would even be humanely possible) and then have some way (and I guess this is where you guys come in) of automatically reading the types and amounts present for each unique ID# and checking to see if that combination is found within the auxiliary table.

Is there any realistic way of doing this or something similar to this?

I can provide more detail if necessary. Sorry if my explaining didn't make any sense; English is not my first language.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Based on the answers I've gotten so far, it seems to be that using IF formulas in some fashion or other would be the way to go but I think this is not viable due to the amount of conditions to check. I'm going to try to reflect most of them off the top of my head:

```
Apples can never be more than MaxA
Oranges can never more than MaxO
Bananas can never be more than MaxB
Pears can never be more than MaxP
If Apples > 30, Oranges has to be at least 1
For every 2 Apples over 30, Oranges has to go up by 1
If Apples is 0, Oranges can't be more than 9
If Pears > 90 then MaxA changes to NewMaxA
```

These go on for a while.

The thing is, as you can probably tell, the 4 amounts of the 4 elements are all tied to each other. It's kind of like a zero-sum thing, in a way. If you increase one of the fruits, the others must go down or up in one way or another.

That's why I thought it was probably easier to have a sheet with all the possible combinations.. but now I'm thinking that doing might not even be possible just due to the sheer number of possibilities?

Is this doable just with formulas?

Answer (score 1):

Because you said you have many rules, I would recommend a separate sheets to track them all. This will make for easier debugging. ([Spencer's suggestion](https://superuser.com/a/1641756/348859) of using conditional formatting would work, too, since it would let you separate the rules. However, it wouldn't be as easy to quick filter to show all the entries that failed for any of those rules.)

First, I edited your data to have someone actually fail the rules:

| Name | Unique ID# | Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |
| John | 969 | Apples | 20 |
| Sarah | 7567 | Apples | 66 |
| Sarah | 7567 | Oranges | 22 |
| Sarah | 7567 | Bananas | 2000 |
| Michael | 1112 | Oranges | 4 |
| Michael | 1112 | Pears | 40 |
| George | 42 | Apples | 9999 |
| George | 42 | Bananas | 20 |
| George | 42 | Pears | 72 |
| George | 42 | Oranges | 21 |

Sarah will fail for having too many bananas and George will fail for not having enough oranges given that he has so many apples.

Next, I made a second tab that ended up looking like this: (the yellow highlighting is manually applied but could easily be conditional formatting, too)

[image: Screenshot]

The row headings are manually typed in and the rest are all formulas. The first two columns are fairly simple. `A2` brings in a sorted list of unique IDs. It also includes the column header and blanks (translated to 0). You could make a more complicated formula to remove those or just ignore them. `B2` will be used to check that all the rules are passed. If you want to filter to see who failed for *any* rule, you'd filter this column. Update its range to include however many columns of rules you have.
A2: `=SORT(UNIQUE(Sheet1!B:B))`
B2: `=AND(C2:D2)`

After that, you'd have one column for each rule. Each column's formula will be unique and, based on just the two examples you gave, possibly very long. Here's C2:

```
=IF(SUMIFS(Sheet1!D:D,Sheet1!B:B,Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!C:C,"Apples")<88,TRUE,SUMIFS(Sheet1!D:D,Sheet1!B:B,Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!C:C,"Oranges")>=22)
```

And D2:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!D:D,Sheet1!B:B,Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!C:C,"Bananas")<=20
```

Continue on in this manner adding columns for each rule. Check each and debug as you go along to make sure they work. Once you're done, be sure to update the formula in B2 to include all your rules and then copy/paste down as far as you need.

---

This should serve as proof of concept and be enough to get you started. There are a few ways this could be improved:

- Ignore the blanks and column header in the A2 formula
- Change the B2 formula to be dynamic, including every rule automatically
- Change all the formulas to be [spill formulas](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531) so you don't have to copy/paste down
- Add conditional formatting to highlight failures
- <sup><sub>Get the people psychological help because they are obsessed with hording fruit</sub></sup>

If you want to make those improvements and don't know how, search around first and come back to ask a new question if you get stuck.

---

## UPDATE BASED ON OP COMMENTS

It seems like you have a long list of interrelated rules. The first thing you should do - if you haven't already - is write out every one of them and determine in what order do they apply. For instance, if one rule increases the max allowable value and another sets the max to a new value, which rule comes first? Does the new max rule overwrite the increase rule? Does the increase rule modify the new max?

Once you have that in order, it is possible to do this all in formulas. It will take time but I bet it's taking a lot of time *now* to determine if each user passes or fails the rules. I would opt for spending a lot of time once rather than a lot of time lots of times. (Here's a relevant [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1205/) to help you determine if it's worth the time and here's another [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1319/) to warn you of the potential danger in attempting this.)

If I was going to tackle this in Excel, the results would look like this:

[image: New Screenshot]

This is the same basic idea as above but expanded to accommodate more rules. I named the first sheet "Data" and the second sheet "Rules".

The formula in A2 is the same: `=SORT(UNIQUE(Data!B:B))`

The formula in B2 is copied for all the cells in B2:E8 (or however many rows you need). Note the `$` that mark a range as a fixed reference rather than a relative reference so it won't change as you copy/paste it elsewhere.

```
=SUMIFS(Data!$D:$D,Data!$B:$B,$A3,Data!$C:$C,B$2)
```

After that, I compute the max allowable values for each fruit. The ranges being referenced will change for each fruit but the idea is the same. Start with the base max value, change it to the last value in the "Set New Max" section for that fruit, then add any values from the "Modify Max" section for that fruit.

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(J3:L3<>""),J3:L3),"maxA")&" + "&SUM(M3:P3)
```

<sup>*Note: This looks a little weird because I had it return text so you could see what it was doing. If the original maxA was, say, 50, then the formula would be `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(J3:L3<>""),J3:L3),50)+SUM(M3:P3)`*</sup>

**KEY POINT:** This is where we determine the order in which rules are applied. Here, I decided to set a new max value first and then modify it as needed. I also set it up so that, if there are multiple rules that can change the new max, later rules overwrite previous ones. IE, if both rules "P>90" and "O<50" (which I made up) apply, then only the "O<50" rule will be applied since it is further to the right.

All the formulas for your rules will have to be custom. The ones that I made up are pretty short since I took the extra step to pull in the "Totals" columns. For instance, here is the formula for "P>90":

```
=IF(E3>90,"newMax","")
```

... and here is "A>30" (`For every 2 Apples over 30, Oranges has to go up by 1`):

```
=ROUNDDOWN(MAX(0,B3-30)/2,0)
```

You can also use the same logic to set and modify min values for each fruit, too. You have said you have many messy rules and can't list them all out here. That's fine, because we're not here to write one hundred formulas for you. I'm just trying to present a format into which you can fit your solution.

The one thing I haven't included above is the final check for if things pass. However, that should be pretty simple once you have the totals, the calculated max (after applying all the rules), and - if needed - the calculated min.

Comment: Wow, this is very good and smells like what I need.. problem is I didn't figure the conditionals would be so convoluted. I think they're way above what I could do on my own. I take it that they'd grow in length and complexity as I introduce more rules. There's a bunch of conditions that I need to check, which mentally I can kinda do on the fly but if I had to actually write it down, I think it'd be pretty complex. Editing the question to reflect an alternative.

Comment: @DND Based on your edit, it looks like there are a long series of rules that need to be applied in a specific order. For instance, are there any rules that increase MaxA? If so, should it get applied before or after If Pears > 90 then NewMaxA? This can be done via formulas but you may be better off with a program such as a VBA script in Excel or some other language you're familiar with. It'd be easy enough to make a table with every user ID and the sum of all their fruits that could then be fed into your rules machine.

Comment: What if I told you that instead of fruits, we're talking about hours and allocation of hours within a given month? Would that make any difference or abbreviate the condition checking, somehow? (I'd imagine it'd be making things *more* complicated, not less. I take it Excel is not particularly good at doing calendar stuff). Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: I forgot to add: the calendar thing is relevant in that it makes the calculating of all the possibilities or the actual writing down of each condition to check a nightmare since the actual number of combinations is probably way too high to do by hand and they're tied to the current calendar, with holidays, weekends, etc.

Comment: I think you melted my brain. It's funny how your brain power goes down as you age. I think I get the gist of what you're doing, i.e: setting rules and prioritize them. The thing is, as I said in my edit, I think there might be a new problem in that the combinations are so many that the resulting number of rules/conditions would be just silly.  I'm thinking I might need a previous system to actually calculate the rules/conditions for me before trying to check for 'approval' and I wouldn't even know where to begin looking for something that. Thanks a lot, though! Your knowledge is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

The auxiliary sheet is one way of doing this, but there are 2 much easier & quicker ways.

- conditional formatting. Highlight cells red if any rules are broken, or alternatively highlight cells green if all rules are met. In this way you could add the different rules separately and then just look through and see from the colours which to approve or refuse.
- Using a fairly complex `IF` formula, to return 'approve' or 'refuse' in a separate column. This would be complicated to write but still quicker than the auxiliary sheet method.

I don't know how proficient you are with formulas, but either of the above would require you to use various formulas nested inside each other, to check all possibilities before outputting 'approve' or 'refuse'. For the example you mentioned:

> if a person has 88 Apples he must have 22 Oranges as well.

The formula to check this would be (in a new column on the sheet, starting at row 3):

```
=IF(AND(C3="Apples", D3=88), IF(SUMIFS(D:D, C:C, "Oranges", A:A, A3)=22, "Approve", "Reject"))
```

You can find all the information you need about individual formulas by googling them. If you need help with how to combine formulas, figure out the exact actions you need the formula to perform, have a try at doing it yourself, and then post it as a question on here or StackOverflow if you can't do it on your own.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input. I figured it'd be theoretically possible nesting IFs (I'm really bad at formulas in general, I usually try to find what I'm looking for somewhere else and edit it to suit my needs, if possible). The thing is, I think I have way too many conditions to check (not sure if there's a limit for nesting IFs). That's why I figured setting up a sheet with all the possible combinations would be easier and clearer, albeit more laborious. Will keep your suggestion in mind, though!

Comment: Further, If there is another data, you can just copy paste on Data Table to get results for that data. Also you can change conditions any time, just by placing new condition values, in condition area.

Comment: Looking to Truth Table Obtained :                                                                 
              Apple  Bananas    Oranges Pears
George  1             1               1           1
John  1             0               0           1
Michael  1                 0               1           0
Sarah  0             1               1           1
    
        65          100             70         30
        Criteria For Minimum Quantity  : If  both Apples>65 AND Bananas more than 100; Only George is eligible. Applying AND Rule

Answer (score 0):

I answer, as I have understood and it may not be desired answer, but it may give some clue to reach desired solution.
I take following 34 Observations as Data. Data Table is in A1:D35

[image: Data Table]

There after below the Data Table I have created Two Way Table; A39:E43 to classify the data.

The formula in first cell B40 for George and Apples,is given below :

=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$35,  $A$2:$A$35,$A40,   $C$2:$C$35,   B$39)

Sumifs adds Qty Column D2:D35, based on Name in A2:A35, and Type C2:C35
It is a multiple sumifs formula.
The $ Signs are used so as to utilise one formula for all.
This formula, adds up the Data Table depending upon the Row and Column variables.

Once Formula is entered in first cell, you get the value as 114.
Now just copy this formula in rest of the cells of two way table.

The following result is obtained.

[image: TWO WAY Table for the above data]

There after CONDITION Table is Obtained as below : I39 to L46 : Output is :

[image: Output Table as per Conditions :]

The conditions given are For Apples Minimum 65, For Bananas Min. 100, For Oranges Minimum 70, For Pears Min. 30. These are entered in I45:L45

This shows that : George satisfies all the conditions, John has passed for Apples and Pears but fails for Bananas and Oranges. Michael is satisfying conditions for Apples and Oranges but poor at Bananas and Pears. Sarah fails to satisfy Minimum Condition for Apple, Rest OK.

The formula for testing the condition is say for Cell I40; For George and Apples is

I40 = IF(B40>$I$45,1,0) similarly all formulae.

One can change the Condition Values to see the new result, so as to arrive at final decision.

I am giving the Worksheet Outlook to understand the formula, if confusion is there.

[image: Worksheet Appearance]

THANKS.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As you said, it's not really what I'd need (and it might not be even possible to do in Excel by itself, anyway) but it was an interesting read and I picked up a thing or two I didn't know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Edit Mode; Format changes, so difficult to comprehend. :

Truth Table is again produced below :

[image: Truth Table]

From this;

If both Apples > 65, ***AND*** Bananas > 100 : Only George is eligible
If ***Either*** Apple Condition **OR** Bananas Condition to be satisfied, then all four are eligible.

If Apples must be > 65 *****AND***** Oranges must be > 70 ; then both George and Michael are eligible, the other two persons John and Sarah fail.

If any two conditions are to be satisfied : Apples & Bananas, A & Oranges, A&Pears, Bananas & Oranges, B& Pears, Oranges&Pears ; then all 4 are eligible.

If any three conditions : ABO, ABP, AOP, BOP are to be satisfied then only two George and Sarah become eligible.

Thanks.